# Am I being asked to prove my assumption?

Tags: linear-transformations

My professor just presented to us his proposition, which is as follows: A functional $L\colon V\to R$ (where $V$ is a vector space and $R$ is a field) is linear if and only if:

1. $L(v+w)=L(v)+L(w)$;
2. $L(av)=aL(v)$ for all $v,w$ in $V$, and all real numbers $a$.

When I try to prove this, I can't help but feel that I am proving the definition of linearity, which is my assumption. Am I making some sort of conceptual mistake?

Comment: I have never seen this be anything but the definition of linearity.

Comment: Are you being asked to verify that a **particular** $L$ is linear?

Comment: No, it was given to us as "Proposition 61" in the lesson manual.

Comment: That seems very odd.

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Perhaps it was an honest typo and was to be "Definition 61" instead of Proposition 61.

Comment: Did he give a definition of linearity for maps between arbitrary vector spaces? I find it odd to define linearity only for functionals.

Comment: The only way I can make sense of being asked to prove something here is if you are asked to prove that this definition is equivalent to some other definition of linear functionals.